# React Big Calendar - Safari fails to render events on week and day view

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I have been using React-big-calendar library for a while now. It works well with Crhome and Firefox, but falls flat on Safari. Safari renders events fine on month-view, but fails to render any events/background-lines or time-column on week/day views.

Here is the code to reproduce issue:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment'
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css'

const eventList = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'Board meeting',
    start: new Date('2022-02-15T07:08:00'),
    end: new Date('2022-02-15T10:10:00')
  }
]
const MainCalendar = () => (
  <div
    style={{
      height: '75vh',
      minHeight: '580px',
      minWidth: '650px',
      background: '#fff',
      padding: '15px'
    }}
  >
    <Calendar
      localizer={momentLocalizer(moment)}
      events={eventList}
      startAccessor="start"
      endAccessor="end"
    />
  </div>
)

export default MainCalendar
```

Here is the month view that works fine
[image: Month view]

Here is the week view, you can see its empty and lacks normal features such as current time indicator(thin line).

[image: Week view]

Here is day view, also broken.
[image: Day view]

Does anybody have any experience about this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a current version of React-Big-Calendar? The documentation site uses the most current version, and everything runs fine in Safari.
[image]